# ARM gcc "empty declaration"

Tags: gcc

The compiler is giving the warning "empty declaration" for the following line of code.

Can someone explain why?  Thanks.

`__attribute__((aligned(8))) byte MyNetWorkBuffers[ ipconfigNUM_NETWORK_BUFFER_DESCRIPTORS ][ NWBUFFER_SIZE ];   __attribute__ ((section (".EnetRcvXmitBuff")));`

Comment: It's because you have a superfluous `;` following `[ NWBUFFER_SIZE ]`.

Comment: Thanks.The format of the line was stated by FreeRTOS..I di not like it but implemented it.  I don't like to see warnings so I ended up just using simple indexing math instead of suggesting it was a double index array and having the compiler do the math.  At least this way I get no warning and I know the indexing is correct.  Thanks again for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a superfluous `;` following `[ NWBUFFER_SIZE ]`. – Mike Kinghan